# Big Parenthesis in Latex

Tags: parentheses

So you know how this code:

```
$(\frac{1}{2})$
```

produces small parenthesis. How would I get bigger parenthesis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in two different ways:

```
$ \displaystyle(\frac{1}{2}) $
```

or

```
$ \left( \frac{1}{2} \right) $
```

Comment: `\displaystyle` does not affect the parenthesis, although it makes the fraction bigger

Comment: You also can choose the size of the delimites, with one of the pairs `\bigl( ... \bigr)`,  `\Bigl( ... \Bigr)`,  `\biggl( ... \biggr)`,  `\Biggl( ... \Biggr)` (in increasing sizes).